# How to set the socks5 proxy in electron?

Tags: electron

I set proxy to report error: err_ NO_ SUPPORTED_ PROXIES。 How to solve this problem?

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('proxy-server', 'socks5://username:password@ip:port')
win.webContents.session.setProxy({proxyRules: 'socks5://username:password@ip:port'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Per Electron's [documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/command-line-switches#--proxy-serveraddressport), the `--proxy-server` command line switch does not support authentication via username and password. As a reason for that, it cites [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=615947) Chromium issue. So, there's no solution to your problem, unfortunately.